# What is the rule that allows `this->` to access members of dependent base classes?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, name-lookup, dependent-name

As we know, the code below is ill-formed because the member `x` is in a dependent base class. However, changing `x` to `this->x` on the indicated line would fix the error.

```
template <typename T>
struct B {
    int x;
};
template <typename T>
struct C : B<T> {
    void f() {
        int y = x; // Error!
    }
};
int main() {
    C<int> c;
    c.f();
}
```

I would like an explanation of how this behaviour is specified in the standard. According to [temp.dep]/3:

> In the definition of a class or class template, if a base class depends on a *template-parameter,* the base class
>   scope is not examined during unqualified name lookup either at the point of definition of the class template
>   or member or during an instantiation of the class template or member.

This seems to explain why using `x` alone fails. The name `x` is looked up at the point of definition, and the base class scope is not examined. However, what if we use `this->x`? Now the name `x` is dependent and its lookup is postponed until instantiation. But the quoted paragraph seems to imply that `x` should not be found *even at instantiation time,* since the lookup of `x` in `this->x` is *still* **unqualified** lookup.

Obviously implementations don't behave this way, and it's widely understood that the base class scope *is* searched once the template is instantiated.

1. Have I misinterpreted the quoted paragraph?
2. Is there a paragraph that specifies the "correct" behaviour?

Comment: This is not unqualified lookup (3.4.1 \[basic.lookup.unqual\]), this is class member access expression lookup (3.4.5 \[basic.lookup.classref\]).

Comment: @n.m. Thanks, I didn't realize class member name lookup was a distinct type of name lookup. You should make that an answer.

Comment: What exactly is a 'dependent base class'? As opposed to say an independent base class? Is there such a thing?

Comment: @EJP In `template <typename T> struct C : B { ... }`, `B` is a not a dependent base class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Class member access expressions (5.2.5. [expr.ref]) don't use unqualified lookup rules, they use class member access lookup rules (3.4.5 [basic.lookup.classref]).

> (2) If the *id-expression* in a class member access (5.2.5) is an unqualified-id, and the type of the object expression
>   is of a class type `C`, the unqualified-id is looked up in the scope of class `C`.

Comment: That doesn’t really say why the answer differs from that for an unqualified name (which obviously considers the scope of any containing class).