# Name lookup for members of the current instantiation and members of unknown specializations

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Does any wording specify how the names of members of unknown specializations and of the current instantiation are looked up? [[temp.res] p10](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#9) has a very informal definition:

> When looking for the declaration of a name used in a template definition, the usual lookup rules are used for non-dependent names. The lookup of names dependent on the template parameters is postponed until the actual template argument is known.

[[temp.dep] p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep#2) specifies that dependent names only apply to unqualified-id's in function calls with type-dependent parameters, so going strictly from this definition, all other names would be non-dependent, which would not makes sense for something like this:

```cpp
template<typename B>
struct A : B
{
  void f()
  {
    this->a += 1; // a here is a member of an unknown specialization, but is not a dependent name
  }
};
```

Here, lookup would have to be postponed until a specialization is instantiated, however, there is no such wording that specifies this that I have found because `a` is not a dependent name.

The only explanation I can think of for this is that the definition *dependent name* differs from "a name that depends on template parameters". Even then, its not defined what it would mean for a name to depend on a template parameter.

As for members of the current instantiation, there is also no wording specifying when they are looked up and bound. For example:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct S
{
  T a;

  void f()
  {
    ++a; // a is a member of the current instantiation, but not a dependent name
  }
};
```

Lookup and binding in this case would not need to be postponed until a specialization is instantiated, as name hiding rules would ensure that `a` would always refer to the member `a`, or another more local name that was declared within the template definition. However, as with the previous case, there is no such wording that actually specifies what would happen in this case either. Certainly, the type of `a` would be dependent on a template parameter, but the actual meaning is easily deduced, as [a function cannot acquire its type from a dependent type](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#spec-8).

Is this just a defect in the standard?

Comment: I think the first half of your question is addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665178/what-is-the-rule-that-allows-this-to-access-members-of-dependent-base-classe).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I understand how it works, what I'm saying is that no wording actually states *when* the lookup occurs formally.

Comment: I would recommended you avoid statements like "Is this just a defect in the standard?" before consensus is reached.  It arguably makes the question "less attractive" :)

Comment: @L.F. Yeah, I get what you're saying but.... The standard has many problems and this is one

Comment: Are you really that sure?  Many times, I announce that I have found a bug in the standard/compiler/library/etc., just to find out that I just misread or neglected a sentence or something along those lines ...  and then feel silly.

Comment: @L.F. That happens to me a lot too :P, however in this case I am almost positive that this is an issue

Comment: OK ...   Anyway, I think the linked question answers your question: member access expressions use a different kind of name lookup.  That's already incompatible with what you state in this question.

Comment: @L.F. I understand that class member access lookup is used, however, it is not formally specified when this lookup is performed (which would have to happen at the point of instantiation)

Comment: https://wg21.link/p1787R4#temp.res resolves this